# php getting part of a URL into a string

Tags: php, html, regex, url

This question is more of a *"what is the best/easiest way to do"*-type-of-question. I would like to grab just the users id from a string such as

```
<a href="/profile.php?rdc332738&amp;id=123456&amp;refid=22">User name</a>
```

I would like to parse the string and get just the `"123456"` part of it.

I was thinking I could explode the string but then I would get `id=123456&blahblahblah` and I suppose I would have to somehow dynamically remove the trash from the end. I think this may be possible with regex but I'm fairly new to PHP and so regex is a little above me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab any character from `id=` up to `&` or `"` (the latter accounts for the case where `id` is put last on the query string)

```
$str = 'a href="/profile.php?rdc332738&amp;id=123456&amp;refid=22">User name</a>';

preg_match('/id=([^&"]+)/', $str, $match);
$id = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) will help here

```
$str = "profile.php?rdc332738&amp;id=123456&amp;refid=22";
parse_str($str);
echo $id; //123456
echo $refid; //22
```

Comment: Seems like `parse_str()` doesn't handle the (correct) form with `&amp;` but only understands single `&`, so this code doesn't work.

Comment: Also, it just works if the string contains **only** the query string, if you include `profile.php?` it gets confused and loses the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
.*id[=]([0-9]*).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

if you explode the string:

```
$string="<a href="/profile.php?rdc332738&amp;id=123456&amp;refid=22">User name</a>"
$string_components=explode('&amp;','$string');
```

The user id part (id=123456) will be:

```
$user_id_part=$string_components[1];
```

then you could do a string replace:

```
$user_id=str_replace('id=','$user_id_part');
```

And you have the user id